# PX Selector behaves strangely during validation

Tags: acumatica

I have this attribute data

[image]

I use this code :

```
  public class CRMORI: PX.Data.Constant<string>
  {
    public CRMORI() : base("CRMORI") { }
  }  


    #region Originelist
    [PXDBString(20, IsUnicode = true, InputMask = "")]
    [PXUIField(DisplayName = "Origine")]
    [PXSelector(typeof(CSAttributeDetail.valueID),typeof(CSAttributeDetail.description),DescriptionField = typeof(CSAttributeDetail.description),SubstituteKey = typeof(CSAttributeDetail.description),ValidateValue = true)]            
    [PXRestrictor(typeof(Where<CSAttributeDetail.attributeID, Equal<CRMORI>>),null)]      
    [PXCustomizeSelectorColumns(typeof(CSAttributeDetail.attributeID),typeof(CSAttributeDetail.description))]        
    public virtual string Originelist { get; set; }
    public abstract class originelist : PX.Data.BQL.BqlString.Field<originelist> { }
    #endregion
```

when I use "Boutique", "Email", "telephone", I have the error "Origine cannot be found in the system"
[image]

but i can choose wechat, whatsapp... without error.

[image]

Comment: Everything looks good for me. I have tried it in my local instance and it worked as expected. Can you try to delete your attribute and recreate it?

Comment: Thanks Zoltan, i thinks the problem is the type field [PXDBLocalizableString(60, IsUnicode = true)] / PX.Objects.CS.CSAttributeDetail, I am on the french version, and I think, the translate is the problem. I create the field CSAttributeDetailExt.usrlibellecrm, it's ok when I put the same caption.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the problem is the substitue key on your PXSelectorAttribute. The reason why wechat and whatsapp work is the id and description fields are the same.

I think you want these for your attributes on this field:

```
[PXDBString(20, IsUnicode = true, InputMask = "")]
[PXUIField(DisplayName = "Origine")]
[PXSelector(typeof(CSAttribute.attributeID),
        typeof(CSAttributeDetail.attributeID), typeof(CSAttributeDetail.description),
        DescriptionField = typeof(CSAttributeDetail.description))]
[PXRestrictor(typeof(Where<CSAttributeDetail.attributeID, Equal<CRMORI>>), null)]
```

I see no need for customize selector columns as you can add your columns to the selector you are already declaring in this field. SubstituteKey is only needed for ID/CD based field configurations. CSAttributes are not one of those cases.